# Rails - Redirecting after Form Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I'm very new to rails, so please forgive my limited knowledge.

I have a controller called users. It has two methods: `new` and `create`.

When `users#new` is called, a form is shown to sign up for an account on my site. I have set up a route for this which makes the URL /signup, like so:

```
match "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
```

When the user navigates to /signup, I create a new `user` instance variable and show them the form, like so:

**UsersController**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end
```

**New View**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<!-- Form code here... -->
<!-- Then at the end: -->
<%= f.submit :value => 'Sign Up' %>
<% end %>
```

When the user submits this form, it sends the data to `users#create`.

My code for `users#create` in `UsersController` looks like so:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Signed Up!'
    else
      render "new"
    end
end
```

The if/else statement is to check if rails was able to create my new user or not. If it was, it redirects to the index no problem.

If it wasn't able to create the user, it renders my new view, and it displays the errors fine.

But, the URL it then gives to us is /users, because when it submits the form it submits to /users. How can I get it so if the signup fails, it will redirect to /signup, and still show the errors that occured?

**UPDATE: routes.rb**

```
Flightdb::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"
  get "home/about"
  get "home/index"
  root :to => 'home#index'
  match 'about' => 'home#about'
  match "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: Could you link your `routes.rb` file? that's happening cause the current route mapped to POST users#create is `/users` if you want it to be `/signup` you'll need to edit it in your routes.rb file, e.g you should remove the route for create and and add a new one, `match "signup" => "users#create", :as => "signup", :method => :post`

Comment: OK - all I want is for the user data to be sent to the create method (as I have), then I want it to **pass back the errors** (if any) to the `new` method, so therefore it shouldn't have to change the url

Comment: @AlexCoplan - that's not how it normally works in rails. Normally you don't redirect if you have errors - you just redisplay the same page... with the exact problem that you mention of possibly having a url that looks bad.

Comment: The way we all normally "get around it" is to have the same url for both get/post - but to route it to two different controller actions (depending on the http verb) - as described by @jpemberthy

Comment: Could someone post an answer on how to 'get around it' then?

Comment: you need `get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"` and `post "signup" => "users#create"`

Comment: @MarianTheisen - it still says '/users' as the URL after I submit (with errors)

Comment: okay, change `resources :users` to `resources :users, :except => [:create, :new]`, maybe you need to extend your form with `:url => signup_path`

Comment: :url makes no difference - and :except causes a routing error on submit :/

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer you don't want to hear is that this usually isn't done. The semantics of the URLs aren't ideal either way. /new implies a fresh new form... but a form with errors is sort of a "partially created" user. The user will never need to use the URL in either case, so no functionality is lost.

Also, consider putting registration and authentication actions on an 'account' (singular) resource. the 'users' controller/resource should probably only be for a backend admin interface. if there are public proiles per user, put them on a 'profiles' resource. put the user's dashboard on a 'dashboard' controller (not a resource).

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the very same issue today and based on Alex's and Marian's comments, I ended up with these changes:

1) in form view:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>
```

2) in routes.rb:

```
get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"
post "signup" => "users#create"
resources :users
root :to => "home#index"
```

I'm a newbie in RoR so I'd welcome comments if there are any side-effect or issues. Or if there is some better way.

Answer (score 0):

the route is indeed corrected this way, but the context of the corresponding controller action "users#new", such as variables that have been initialized by the action, is lost.
So we end up in a kind of unstable situation where we're neither in the "new" context nor outside of it...
How to control that context is the question ? Maybe through ActiveModel::Validator

I'm not sure where and how to alter this behaviour...